# Editing sprite shading to change perspective?

Tags: sprites, art, shading, pixel-art

I'm currently developing an RPG in Java with some of my friends, and one of my tasks is to do the pixel art. I'm a beginner at it, but I know that I'll get better in time. 
I recently finished the concept of our main character (after many, many revisions), however, because the game is going to be in a 3/4 top down perspective; how would I edit the shading of the sprite to show this? Obviously a frontal view will not look right. My shading skills are not the best though, even with this sprite (some parts appear to be flat).

Below I have the sprite attached.

[image: Alice, the MC]

I did read something that said it would be harder to make higher resolution sprites for beginners (tile size is 32 x 32, MC is almost 2 tiles tall); however, it is a difficulty I am willing to deal with.

Thanks, 
Nelson

Comment: You might take a look at the ever famous [So You Want To Be A Pixel Artist?](http://www.yarrninja.com/pixeltutorial) tutorial.

Comment: Particularly part 13: let there be light. You've got a good base to work with (dear sweet raptor jesus that face looks really d̶e̶l̶i̶c̶i̶o̶u̶s̶  well drawn!) though, so props there!